# Is there a way to backup emails from OWA?

Tags: email, outlook, email-client, outlook-web-app

I am using OWA on IE8 and am do not have any email client like outlook installed. We just access email in the browser using OWA.
Is there a script (maybe a scraper) that backs up the emails?

How do I go about writing such a script, is there a OWA API?

I googled a lot but every solution first syncs OWA to exchange or outlook or some other email client and then backs it up. I do not have that luxury.

I have python installed, so a simple email client script written in python can be helpful too, if it can somehow be configured to logina nd read emails from OWA.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

http://davmail.sourceforge.net/ can be used as a proxy to expose OWA folders via IMAP and POP3.

> The main goal of DavMail is to provide standard compliant protocols in front of proprietary Exchange. This means .. IMAP to browse messages on the server in any folder, POP to retrieve inbox messages only, .. Thus any standard compliant client can be used with Microsoft Exchange.

Then question becomes how to make backup of IMAP or POP3 server.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to export mails in bulk from OWA, as far as I know.

As you suggested the only way would be using Outlook..